# calculate total score in percentage

Tags: php

```
<?php
$value1 = rand (1,10);
$value2 = rand (1,10);
?>
<form action="mathq.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="input1a" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>" class="value" />

<input type="text" value="x" class="equa" />

<input type="text" name="input2a" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" class="value" />

<input type="text" value="=" class="equa" />

<input id="answer" type="text" name="answer" value="" class="answer" /><br /><br />




<input type="submit" value="Submit answer" class="submit">

<INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Clear all fields of this form">

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['input1a']) && isset($_POST['input2a']) && isset($_POST['answer'])) {

$result = $_POST['answer'];
$input1a = $_POST['input1a'];
$input2a = $_POST['input2a'];


if (!empty($input1a) && !empty ($input2a) && !empty($result)) {
    //echo '<span class="success">Success!&nbsp;&nbsp;';

}
     if ($result == $input1a * $input2a)
    {
        print($input1a . ' x ' . $input2a . ' = ' . '<span class="correct">' . $result . '</span>' . '<br />Correct!');

    }
    else
    {
        print($input1a . ' x ' . $input2a . ' = ' . '<span class="incorrect">' . $result . '</span>' . '<br />Wrong!<br /> The correct answer was: ' . '<span class="correct">' . $input1a * $input2a . '</span>');
    }

}
?>
```

I was wondering how i could calculate total score of right answers after the user hits the submit button? How could i create a loop that would go through the rand number of problems and after it goes through once it exits and outputs the person score as percentage of right or wrong answers.  I'm stuck on this part.

I was also thinking of another way i could tackle this problem.

A user goes through the rand number of math problems once he is done with practices problem he or she hits Done button and it outputs his score.  Can you give me guidance how i can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a place to store data whilst questions are in progress.

This would commonly be done in Session data, or in a local database. It could be done in cookies, but not advisable. It could also be done in a flat text file.

You'd need to count how many questions done, how many right answers, and you can then derive the resulting % to feed back to the user.

Without somewhere to store the intermediate data, you cannot do this.

Comment: If i wanted to store it in the session data how would i go about doing that? I thinking database is bit much for this type of problem, since only data is store is how many questions are done and how many are right.

Comment: So im thinking session would be the best to store the users temporary score data, since its only important for short period of time.  Would i create a new session variable and compare it to the result variable?  output the total score calculation after form "done" button is pressed?  

$score = $_SESSION["answer"] ;

Comment: You could start the session on the first page, setup some initial values etc. You could store the current question values in the Session too. Then each time the user answers a question, you could then update these values. Separate the files into a Question page and an Answer page that processes the form and displays the results. This would give a simple solution, enough to get you started. There are more complex issues that can arise, such as the user refreshing the answer page, or accessing that page directly, but understand the easier stuff first :)